# Doctrine 2.3 & 2.4 MappingException class not found

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I’m unable to get Doctrine 2 working and I'm hoping someone with a better eye can point out the problem.

I’ve used version 1.2 extensively in the past and it was an absolute breeze but versions 2.3 and 2.4 just won’t fly after following the documentation exactly and trying it with different drivers.

I've used the orm:clear-cache functions from the console as suggested elsewhere and I'm not using the eAccelerator cache that some users have had trouble with.

I’m able to create the EM and reverse engineer mappings in all formats however I receive a MappingException the minute I try to do anything useful.

**The following is relevant to all examples below:**

```
//Paths & Setup
$paths = array(“/home/site/public_html/deployment/Models”);
$proxyDir = “/home/site/public_html/deployment/System/DoctrineProxies”;
$cacheDir = “/home/site/public_html/deployment/System/DoctrineCache”;
$proxyNamespace = 'DoctrineProxies';
$devMode = 1;

// connection
$dbParams = array('driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
                  'user'     => $this->user,
                  'password' => $this->pass,
                  'dbname'   => $this->dbname,
                  'host'     => $this->host
                  );
```

**Firstly, I reverse engineered the mappings from a database successfully as follows:**

```
//Configure and create the EM
$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createConfiguration($devMode);
$driver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($paths);      
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
$config ->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
$config ->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config ->setProxyDir($proxyDir);       
$config ->setProxyNamespace($proxyNamespace);
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_ALWAYS); 
\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Autoloader::register($proxyDir, $proxyNamespace);
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

//Load DB Driver
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl(
            new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver(
                $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
            )
        );

//Generate metadata info
$cmf = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
$cmf->setEntityManager($em);
$metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();

//Export metadata to models
$cme = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ClassMetadataExporter();
$exporter = $cme->getExporter('annotation', $paths[0]);
$exporter->setMetadata($metadata);
$eg = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator;
$exporter->setEntityGenerator(new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator);
$exporter->export();
echo “DONE!”;
```

Now I have 2 Annotation mappings as follows:

/home/site/public_html/deployment/Models/Node.php
/home/site/public_html/deployment/Models/Page.php

**Contents of the Node mapping:**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Node
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Node")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Node
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="URL", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $url;

}
```

I receive a MappingException when trying to perform a retrieval and the result is exactly the same if I use the Yaml driver:

```
//Configure and create the EM exactly as above
//…

//Retrieve a node
$node = $em->find(‘Node', 14);
```

**Result:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class 'Node' does not exist
```

**The command line tool orm:info produces this result:**

```
Found 2 mapped entities:

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]  
Class 'Node' does not exist 

orm:info
```

If I use the Yaml mappings that were reverse engineered with the exporter and the Yaml driver I can generate Annotated entities using the command line tools (orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="1") so that leads me to believe the mappings are valid and visible to doctrine however I still receive the same MappingException when I try to use any of the mappings.

Comment: I know this is old but did you try "composer dump-autoload" ?